# ASHX sends HttpWebRequest with Impersonation On, which works to URLs on same server but not on Remote ArcGIS server

Tags: asp.net, impersonation, ashx

This is a complicated issue, so bear with me.

Scenario: using a ASHX proxy to relay request to an ArcGIS server.
Trying to use ASP.NET impersonation, so that the logged in ASP.NET user credentials are used by the proxy, when sending request to the ArcGIS server.

Issue: the proxy request to ArcGIS server is refused 401, even though I know the impersonated account (sean.ryan-B + sean.ryan) does have access.

There are 4 machines:

```
1. machine hosting proxy page.  I am logged in as: sean.ryan-B
2. a test machine. I am logged in as sean.ryan-B
3. my laptop. I am logged in as sean.ryan
4. the arcgis server.

All 4 machines are on the same domain.

web.config:
  <authentication mode="Windows"/>
   <identity impersonate="true" />  <!-- userName="EUROPE\sean.ryan-B" password="xxx" -->
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>

Test-1. Opening a test page, in same web app as proxy, via the proxy:
http://myHost.com/sean/ProxyAsp.Net/ArcGisProxy.ashx?http://myHost.com/sean/ProxyAsp.Net
[ok on all boxes 1-3]

This looks OK - the impersonation seems look OK, 
since with impersonation OFF:    WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name = the AppPool account
    with impersonation ON:    WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name = EUROPE\sean.ryan or EUROPE\sean.ryan-B

Test-2. opening an image that is hosted on the same IIS (but a different site), via the proxy:
http://myHost.com/sean/ProxyAsp.Net/ArcGisProxy.ashx?http://myHost.com:10400/sites/CaSPER/SiteAssets/CaSPER.jpg
[ok on boxes 1-3]

Test-3. opening the ArcGIS map URL, via the proxy:
http://myHost.com/sean/ProxyAsp.Net/ArcGisProxy.ashx?http://mapserver1.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Global/2D_BaseMap_SurfaceGeology/MapServer?f=json&callback=dojo.io.script.jsonp_dojoIoScript1._jsonpCallback
[fails on boxes 2,3 but succeeds on the proxy host (box 1)!]

code for the ASHX code-behind:

    public partial class ArcGisProxy : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState //ASHX     implements IReadOnlySessionState in order to be able to read from session
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpResponse response = context.Response;

                // Get the URL requested by the client (take the entire querystring at once
                //  to handle the case of the URL itself containing querystring parameters)
                string uri = context.Request.Url.Query;
                uri = uri.Substring(1); //the Substring(1) is to skip the ?, in order to get the request URL.

                System.Net.HttpWebRequest req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

                {
                    req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; //this works on local box, with -B account.  this is the account the web browser is running under (rather than the account logged into CaSPER with, as ASHX has separate server session).

                    req.ImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
                }

                //to turn off caching: req.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
                req.Method = context.Request.HttpMethod;
                req.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
                req.Referer = context.Request.Headers["referer"];

                // Set body of request for POST requests
                req.Method = "GET";

                // Send the request to the server
                System.Net.WebResponse serverResponse = null;
                try
                {
                    serverResponse = req.GetResponse();
                }
                catch (System.Net.WebException webExc)
                {
                    //logger.Log(GetMyUrl(), webExc, context.Request);

                    response.StatusCode = 500;
                    response.StatusDescription = webExc.Status.ToString();
                    response.Write(webExc.ToString());
                    response.Write(webExc.Response);
                    response.Write("Username = " + context.User.Identity.Name + " " + context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated + " " + context.User.Identity.AuthenticationType);
                    response.End();
                    return;
                }

                // Set up the response to the client
                ....
                    ......

                response.End();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

note: the following changes, meant proxy request to the map server DOES succeed:

a) set the identity in the web.config to explicitly set username, password to the sean.ryan-B account:

-OR-

b) set the App Pool account to be sean.ryan-B and turn OFF impersonation in the web.config file.

however these changes are not acceptable for Production.

The problem seems to be that:
- ASP.NET impersonation works well enough for test page + image hosted on same IIS (tests 1 and 2)
but NOT well enough for the map server.

as far as I know, the ArcGIS map server is using Negotiate, and then Kerberos authentication.

With WireShark, I monitored a successful proxy request, and found:
after 401, proxy sends GET with AUTH using SPNEGO (Kerberos)

Has anyone had similar issue with ArcGIS proxy ?

My theory is, that the impersonation on box 1 'works better', because browser is running on same box as the proxy.

Could the ArcGIS Server (or the IIS site it is using) be restricted to prevent accepting impersonation ?

Any suggestions welcome ...
 p.s. had a hard time getting this post through - had to format most of it as code, as s-o is detecting it as source code !

Comment: update: perhaps the account of the AppPool does not have permission to Impersonate on the IIS account of the ArcGIS server ?

Comment: update: I believe this is an example of what people call "double hop issue in NTLM".

I will do some more research ... a possible workaround is to use RunWithElevatedPriviledges() but that may also hit the double-hop issue ...

Comment: relevant articles:

Impersonation & SharePoint:
http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2012/05/30/impersonation-elevation-of-privileges/

NTLM double hop issue:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/besidethepoint/archive/2010/05/09/double-hop-authentication-why-ntlm-fails-and-kerberos-works.aspx

Comment: SOLUTION:  wrapping the request with SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(), results in a successful response from the IIS on ArcGIS box, even WITH impersonate=true in web.config.  note: not sure why this works, since there is still a double hop.  perhaps the AppPool account is setup for Kerberos.

note: the Impersonation level needs to be:
TokenImpersonationLevel.Delegation

Comment: note: the URL to proxy *must* include the SP site (and NOT be a URL to global folder on the SP farm).  this is so that SPContext.Current is not null, so that SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges() will work

Comment: note: SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges() succeeds, independently of the value of impersonate in web.config